# What are the rules for reading numbers before a foreign counter-word?

Tags: readings, counters

Is there a rule of thumb for knowing the reading of a number when it is written in western numerals, and is followed by a loaned counter-word?

For example, how would you pronounce the "1" in `１セット`? My first thought it to say `「いっセット」`, but as far as I know it could just as easily be `「ひとセット」` or `「いちセット」`. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word) does not cover loan-word counters, and I cannot find anything on this topic.

Comment: There are a few answers about the general issue below, but I thought it might be helpful to note that １セット *in particular* is often pronounced ワンセット...

Comment: @Matt Seriously? That's...uhh, strange to say the least. I hadn't even considered that they'd actually be trying to speak English...やれやれ

Comment: @silvermaple Hard to say it's any more strange or any less Japanese than ワンピース.

Comment: @Louis Hmmm, I see your point, but I think there's a difference between a comic and a newspaper (where I found 1セット).

Comment: @silvermaple I used to think it was about the manga too, but I've only ever heard it used as an [outfit](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=%e3%83%af%e3%83%b3%e3%83%94&view=small&FORM=VBCIRS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to extrapolate the rules for Japanese counters onto foreign-counter-words.

Extracted from [Nihongoresources](http://grammar.nihongoresources.com/doku.php?id=counters#idxenglishrules_for_%E4%B8%80_%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1_counting_pronunciation_rules_%E4%B8%80_%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1):

---

Rules for 一

- When followed by a counter starting with a syllable from the か—, さ— or た—column, いち becomes いっ
- When followed by a counter starting with a は—column syllable, いち becomes いっ and the counter changes to a 'p' sound

---

Rules for 三:

- When followed by a counter starting with a は—column syllable, that syllable changes to a 'b' sound

---

Rules for 六:

- When followed by a counter starting with a か—column syllable, ろく becomes ろっ
- When followed by a counter starting with a は—column syllable, ろく becomes ろっ and the counter changes to a 'p' sound

---

Rules for 八:

- When followed by a counter starting with a か—, さ— or た—column syllable, はち becomes はっ
- When followed by a counter starting with a は—column syllable, はち becomes はっ and the counter changes to a 'p' sound

---

Rules for 十:

- When followed by a counter starting with a か—, さ— or た—column syllable, じゅう may become じっ or じゅっ
- When followed by a counter starting with a は—column syllable, じゅう can become either じっ or じゅっ and the counter changes to a 'p' sound

---

In short I don't think it matters if the counter is of Japanese origin or foreign origin. It depends on the first syllable of the counter.

Comment: Maybe extrapolation does not always work? For instance 2パック is ふたパック and 2泊 is にはく. は might not be the same rule as ぱ though... for 1 both are ぱ and I guess it would be ひとパック and いっぱく (even though 1パック does not make much sense)

Comment: That's a good point. What happens when it's 2~, 4~, 5~, 7~, 9~? I suppose we have to look at them case by case? Or alternatively is it possible to treat the "foreign-counter-word" as a noun itself to be counted? This way we force the situation to be [Number]+[Japanese Counter]+[Foreign Word]. I.e. ふたつパック. and eliminate the problem of using the foreign word as a counter.

Comment: It is not appropriate to say "voices to a 'p' sound". "p" is an unvoiced counterpart to the voiced "b". Furthermore, "h" does not change to "p". It is the other way around: "p" changes to "h". "p" is the underlying sound. The kana transcription system is misleading in that it adds the 半濁点 for "p", making it look like "p" and "b" are derived from "h".

Comment: @sawa I don't understand what it means to say that one sound or the other is 'underlying' here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It has two senses. One, historically, the sounds pronounced today as `h` were originally `p`. Two, (depending on the theoretical framework), there is an abstract representation form called underlying representation, and phonological rules apply to that so that the actual output is different from that.

Comment: @sawa If you don't mind me asking. What do I have to study to know what you know?

Comment: @Flaw As for the historical change from "p" to "h", it is widely accepted and is a famous fact in 国語学 (traditional Japanese study) or 日本語学 (modern Japanese study) or Japanese linguistics. You may want to see this: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E8%A1%8C%E8%BB%A2%E5%91%BC. For the general idea that there is an underlying sound and that it changes according to rules, it is standardly accepted within phonology, a subfield of linguistics.

Comment: The claim that "p" changes to "h" not just historically but also within present Japanese when you produce sentences is not necessarily shared by everyone but is quite common within phonology or Japanese linguistics. One prominent figure who claimed this is James McCawley, a linguist who studied Japanese.

Comment: @Flaw Sorry, I gave you the wrong link. This link is more relevant: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%94%87%E9%9F%B3%E9%80%80%E5%8C%96

Comment: @NicolasRaoul In my experience, 1パック is いっぱっく, while 1泊 is いっぱく. In my life so far, I've not yet come across ひとはく and ひとぱっく.

Answer (score 7):

Following [this advice on Meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers), I'm going to throw in an answer I'm pretty sure of, but could be corrected on.

Scanning down the [list of example counters in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Common_counters_by_category) you linked to, *every one of them* starts with `一{いち}`, or it's [phonetically adjusted equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Euphonic_changes) like `一{いっ}`. There were a lot, though, so maybe I missed one or two exceptions.

Thus, the rule of thumb I think you're looking for is:

> Unless you already know for sure it's an exception, always guess the
>   counter starts with `一{いち}/一{いっ}`

I think this could be said for just about all counters, not just foreign words. Since you're asking specifically about "loan-counters," though, the point is that this rule of thumb would encompass them as well.

I can't think of an example exception, along the lines of `一人{ひとり}` and `二人{ふたり}`, that uses a loan-word in the counter.