# 1カ所: いっかしょ or いちかしょ?

Tags: pronunciation, counters

What is the correct pronunciation for `1カ所` ?

It means: 1 place

Context:

> ユーティリティ関数として定義されているわりには1カ所からしか呼ばれていない。

It is defined as a utility function, but only called in one place.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for reading numbers before a foreign counter-word?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4027/542)

Comment: Also related: [What are the origins of ヶ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/347/78)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pronounced ikkasho (いっかしょ).